# How to test array console input

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-5.7, laravel-testing

I prefer to use "almost TDD" in my daily workflow. And a few days ago I've faced this issue.

Imagine a command with such signature.

`protected $signature = 'sync:store {--storeId= : Sync stores}';`

In my test-suite I've added

```
   $this->artisan('sync:store', [
      '--storeId'  => [1],
   ]);
```

Everything is ok, BUT the next day command was NOT working. I've overlooked the `*` in my signature. That's why the test was green, but the option was not working.

Is there a way to verify, that exactly the array notation works as needed? Cause this is a real-life issue I have faced.

Comment: Have you looked over [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/console-tests) ?

Comment: I don't see a `*` in a signature? I see you testing a different command than the one you've posted though?

Comment: @Loek that's what I'm saying :) I have overlooked the `*` in `--storeId`. And now looks like there is NO way to test it.

Comment: @JulienMetral yep. No what I'm asking about :D

Comment: @Loek the problem is that the test is green even though the command is not working.

Comment: @D.R. you need to add more code. I don't see signatures, I don't see missing `*`s and I don't see tests being asserted?

Comment: @Loek The first code block (in grey) is the signature. the second grey block is the test. You definitely should be able to see it :D

Comment: But the signature is `sync:store` and the test is running `sync:shopify-store-order-transactions`? And ctrl + f `*` isn't returning anything in your code?

Comment: @Loek, oh, sorry :) Overlooked. I've updated the `artisan` command. And yes, you should NOT be able to see the `*`. And theoretically, the test should fail, but it passes. That's the issue.

Comment: Does it pass though? Now you run the command and then... Nothing? The test doesn't assert anything. It just checks it can run the command and that's it AFAIK. In other words, the test might not fail but it might not pass either when you don't assert anything. Then it shows up as a completed test without checks.